# double datePicker in single android activity

Tags: java, android, datepicker, showdialog

im develping an android app where on one activity the user needs to select two different dates. i've followed approximately [this] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm) tutorial but don't undestand how to get over the following thing:
when i invoke

```
showDialog(999);
```

then

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, oYear, oMonth, oDay);
    }
    return null;
}
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {




    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int oYear, int oMonth, int oDay) {
        order.setOrderDate(oDay,oMonth,oYear);
    }
};
```

since i need to do the exact same operation (i.e. set for pDay,pMonth,pYear) a date that the user enters pressing on a different button, how can i do this?
since the

```
showDialog(999);
```

is called from diffrent methods

```
 public void setOrderDate(View view) {
    showDialog(999);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}


 public void setPickupDate(View view) {
    showDialog(999);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

is there something that I can pass along with showDialog to identify when the shoDialog is called from the first or the latter?

Comment: your question is not clear.please explain more

Comment: the user needs to set two dates in one activity: order date (oYear, oMonth, oDay) and pickup day(pYear,pMonth,pDay).
the user selects these using the calendar dialog that showDialog(999) provides.
when showDialog(999) is called, it invokes the two methods i've insert in the second block of code in my question. these are built to deal with the setting of order day: i pass oYear,oMonth,oDay in this call `return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, oYear, oMonth, oDay);`
since the method in which this line is found, is called even from the showDialog that should set the pickup date

Comment: how can i set pYear, pMonth and pDay?